# R read all files in a directory

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read and merge together all the csv files in a directory. I found this excellent SO answer: [Importing multiple .csv files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I am able to list the files (they are in my home directory in a sub-folder called "test"):

```
library(data.table)  
files <- list.files(path = "test",pattern = ".csv")
print(files)
```

This correctly prints the content of the directory.

When I try to load them using

```
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
data <- rbindlist(temp)
```

I get `File 'xyz.csv' does not exist. Include one or more spaces to consider the input a system command.`

Do I have to somehow specify the path again? I fought that this information is already contained in the file object. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I guess the error is in the `temp <- lapply(files ,...)` step?  Can you try with `library(readr); lapply(files, read_csv)`

Comment: @akrun Yes, the error is on that particular line

Comment: I don't know if this is some delimiter issue, can you try `library(readr); lapply(files, read_csv)` or even the `base R`, i.e. `lapply(files, read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: I can't seem to be able to install this library... It is stuck at "select CRAN mirror" with no selection displayed. I wanted to use the data.tables read functionality since it offers better performance. The base R package produces the same error

Comment: @Smaji Then, try to exclude that file and read all others.  Then read the concerned file separately. i.e. files1 <- setdiff(files, "xyz.csv"); lapply(files1, fread)`

Comment: Could it be a path issue? (path different from working directory, so files are not found?) Does the issue persist if you use `full.names=T` inside list.files?

Comment: @Heroka you seem to have just beaten me to the punch there. Although I would advise against `full.names=T` and rather suggest `full.names=TRUE`. It can cause problems using `T` as it can be used as a variable which could be set to `FALSE` whereas assignment to the name `TRUE` is prohibited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect the problem lies in the path to the files. Most likely because your working directory is one level up from the directory `"test"`. Try:

```
    list.files(path = "test", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
```

The `full.names` argument will include the path to the files in it's output.

Comment: Had the same issue, including `full.names` is a must if the files are not located in the working directory.